# Why does WebSphere refuse app install and doesn't specify a reason?

Tags: java, websphere, web-deployment, m2eclipse

I'm currently a developer for an agency where unfortunately we use IBM WebSphere anywhere and everywhere... I've searched this site, IBM documentation as well as too many pages of Google search and cannot find an an answer.

The issue I've been plagued with the last year is that whenever I deploy a web app .EAR to WAS 8.5.5.12 through Eclipse, it refuses to install it at all. Usually, upon adding an eligible workspace application to the WAS, it will immediately start the installation process. This is just not the case in my experience. My SystemOut log below isn't very helpful:

```
[9/11/17 11:03:11:138 EDT] 00000059 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1009I: An attempt is made to start the deferment-forbearance-ear-2.11.1.01-SNAPSHOT application.
[9/11/17 11:03:11:138 EDT] 00000059 ApplicationMg W   WSVR0215W: Starting application, deferment-forbearance-ear-2.11.1.01-SNAPSHOT, failed.  The application is not installed.
[9/11/17 11:03:11:216 EDT] 00000059 DMAdapter     I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.DMAdapter getAnalysisEngine FFDC1009I: Analysis Engine using data base: C:\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\properties\logbr\ffdc\adv\ffdcdb.xml
[9/11/17 11:03:11:263 EDT] 00000059 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_ccf605e1_17.09.11_11.03.11.1545417859609336185341.txt com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke 679
[9/11/17 11:03:11:325 EDT] 00000059 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_ccf605e1_17.09.11_11.03.11.2635024215334184810588.txt com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke 351
[9/11/17 11:03:11:372 EDT] 00000059 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_ccf605e1_17.09.11_11.03.11.3251626089514458391860.txt com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service 212
```

There are however, 3 FFDC logs created, the first of which specifying this:

```
[9/11/17 11:03:11:154 EDT]     FFDC Exception:javax.management.MBeanException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke ProbeId:679 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1@85728e7a
javax.management.MBeanException: Exception thrown in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation startApplication
   at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1195)
   at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
   at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
   at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
   at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
   at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
   at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
   at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:488)
   at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:324)
   at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:532)
   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationWarning: Application deferment-forbearance-ear-2.11.1.01-SNAPSHOT not installed
   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1342)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
   at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
   at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
   at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:424)
   at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
   at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
   at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
   ... 17 more
```

The other 2 FFDC text docs look similar. I'm not the most experienced web dev so I'm not sure if that output should really tell me much. I've tried deleting (cleanly) old profiles/servers and creating new ones but to no avail. I've also tried switching WebSphere's SDK and JRE from 1.6 to 1.8 to try and fix this issue but still no results. This happens on multiple applications I've tried as well. Any suggestions on what to do about this? Maybe where else I can search possibly for more revealing data on why this is happening? I can absolutely provide more information on my setup if necessary, tried to be as close as possible to proper question etiquette.

Comment: Do you happen to have logs from the actual install process?  The stacks you pasted in are from the application start, not install, and the complaint is that the app you're trying to start isn't installed.  My guess is that something failed during the install step that left incomplete data somewhere (maybe the binaries got copied but some metadata wasn't updated, or something like that).

Comment: @Jarid In the server's log directory (C:\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1) there isn't anything related to installation. Do you know where I might find logs concerning deployed app installs? I also checked most of the folders in the parent directory and basically dug all over the IBM WAS folders looking for something about app installs...

Comment: It would depend on how you installed the app, but there should be something in SystemOut.log if the server was running at the time, and I think wsadmin.traceout should have something if you installed with wsadmin on the command line.